# VBA/VBScript to Word Template document (.docm/.dotx)

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I have an application that at this point calls a VBScript file with ~11 parameters. Those parameters need to be caught and saved. Then a Word template document needs to be called and filled in. What would be the best way to do this? I'm searching for a solution, but apparently VBScript does not support the same assignments as VBA so I'm walking against a wall.

Showing the arguments:

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
For I = 0 to args.Count -1
    Wscript.Echo args(I)
Next
```

Opening Word:

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
```

Comment: Once you've invoked the `Word.Application` class you can use all the properties and methods the same as your would in VBA. Just use `oWord` instead of `Application` and use literals instead of `wd_____` constants

Comment: Would the following article be a good example? http://www.devhut.net/2010/09/17/vba-word-update-fill-in-document-form-fields/

Comment: Sure, that would work as starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with the following script.

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Dim wordIds
    wordIds = Array("idDate", "idName", "idCompany")
Dim oWord
Dim oDoc
Dim sDocPath

' If the next line gives an error continue with the line that comes next '
On Error Resume Next
    ' Look if a Word object is already open '
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

' If number of errors is higher or lower than 0 create a new Word object '
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

' Specify the Word document and open it for the user '
sDocPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\template.dotm"
Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(sDocPath)
oApp.Visible = True

' Iterate through all arguments and fill them in the ContentControls'
for I = 0 to args.Count -1
    oDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag(wordIds(I))(1).Range.Text = args(I)
Next
```

Script receives arguments, saves what kind of Tags have been used within the Word document (I have used Rich Text Content Control), checks if the Word is open and if not opens it, grabs the needed document and finally fills the Content Control with the received arguments. Tested with Word 2013.
I'm probably gonna change the script but this could be a guide line for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Vague answer to a vague question, but generally speaking:

Use `oWord` instead of `Application`:

```
oWord.CheckGrammar(someString) '// Instead of Application.CheckGrammar()
```

Use literals instead of `wd______` constants:

```
myDoc.SaveAs2("SomeDoc.docx", 12) '// Instead of myDoc.SaveAs2("SomeDoc.docx", wdFormatXMLDocument)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would have to explain it. Maybe this way. I have an application that calls the vbscript and sends the needed data to it through parameters. Those parameters need to be caught. With those parameters as data the vbscript needs to fill in a Word template document that already has placeholders for all the data (things like: name, surname, date, etc..). Thanks for the example.

Comment: In that case the script you found earlier would be perfect for that

Comment: I already tried the script but each time I had a syntax error with the following like "On Error GoTo Error_Handler_Exit".